# Javascript Scoping Issue in Backbone Model / Collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, scope, marionette

I'm working with a tree structure, so i need to do some pretty wonkey finds whenever I want to work my way from the leaves to the trunk, but I'm basically trying to create a function that I can pass a function to and apply / call / bind / something the original context so that I can see the variables that i had originally. An explaination would be awesome.

```
layerListView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({    
    updateSelectedModelsInTree: function () {
        var col = myApp.request('someOtherCollection');
        this.collection.startFromLeaves(function (m) {
            this.updateSelected(m);
            // col is undefined in here
        }, this);
    }
});
layerCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    startFromLeaves: function (doToModel, context) {
        if (!this.models) return;
        for (var i = this.models.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var model = this.models[i],
                tag = this.models[i].get('tag');
            if (tag == 'branch') this.startFromLeaves(arguments);
            doToModel.call(context, model);
        }
    }
});
```

so i'm stuck here, and all I want to do is to be able to see the col variable inside of the top function that is passed into startFromLeaves. I have no idea how to use call / bind / apply, but I'm guessing that my context is what is throwing everything off.

Comment: `col` should be visible there, are you sure that `myApp.request('someOtherCollection')` isn't returning `undefined`?

Comment: it most definitely is returning the collection that it is supposed to. it's just that, as soon as i get inside of the function that i pass to startFromLeaves, it does not exist

Comment: But `col` is grabbed through closure, it has nothing to do with `this` or context or anything like that. Any chance of a demo? I'm guessing that the code in your question isn't telling the whole story.

Comment: I am not using a closure anywhere. I am passing a function to another function. I don't think that is the same thing.

Comment: (1) Read [MDN on closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures). (2) You're doing the equivalent of http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/mr8q2rss/ which works as expected.

Comment: Are you sure `myApp.request('someOtherCollection')` is not an asynchronous call?

Comment: you were right @muistooshort it was available, i just did not see it because i was using the chrome debug tools. If you put an answer, i can close this one out or do whatever I'm supposed to. not sure what's kosher.

Comment: I'd probably delete the question, it was based on some common confusion and you have it sorted out now so we're all good. If you can't delete it, let me know and I'll flag it for the moderators to clean up.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the bind function on [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)

This allows you to pass a function that has the this context set.  So for instance you could do

```
updateSelectedModelsInTree: function () {
    var col = myApp.request('someOtherCollection');
    this.collection.startFromLeaves(_.bind(function (m) {
        this.updateSelected(m);
        // col is undefined in here
    }, this));
}
```

"this" inside your function will now always be the "this" that contains "updateSelectedModelsInTree"